# Receiving transactions in prune mode

Tags: wallet, pruning

I am new to Bitcoin.  I have downloaded the whole blockchain but I still can't access my wallets because I get a popup telling me to use prune mode.  My question is: I know that I have received transactions that I have not yet seen in my wallet.  If I run prune mode, will I lose those deposits since they are not yet in my wallet?

Answer (score 1):

> I am new to Bitcoin.

Welcome !

> I have downloaded the whole blockchain but I still can't access my wallets because I get a popup telling me to use prune mode.

You might not have enough disk space (hence why you're not able to see your funds).

> If I run prune mode, will I lose those deposits since they are not yet in my wallet?

No, not at all.
By using prune mode you'll be able to fully sync to the tip (current last block of the chain) and thus see your funds, which you apparently cannot without prune mode because of your disk space.